# heapsort coding for python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, heapsort

```
def heapSort(lst):

    heap = arrayHeap.mkHeap(len(lst), arrayHeap.less)
    alst = list(lst)
    while alst != []:
        v = alst.pop(0)
        arrayHeap.add (heap, v)

    while heap.size != 0:
        w = arrayHeap.removeMin(heap)
        alst.append(w)
    return last
```

is this a valid heap sort function?

Comment: Without seeing the code for `arrayHeap`, nobody can say.  Although heapsort is almost always coded in-place, so the most sensible answer is "no".

Comment: `pop(0)` makes your code O(n^2), so no. This is not a working heapsort.

Comment: well this is not a in-place heap sort. and the array heap function is pretty long....

Comment: Also, you have a `return last` instead of `return alst`, so it should have been obvious that this doesn't work if you tried it.

Comment: i m running this function, and yes it takes a very long time.

Comment: last is a typo. in the actual code alst is returned

Comment: Copy/paste is quicker and more reliable than retyping your code into the question. Copy/paste it next time.

Comment: Despite the inplace issue, you insert n element into a heap individually, which costs O(n*logn),this can be done with a heap merge which only costs O(n)

Comment: i did copy/paste...my comp did the autocorrect that caused the typo. the heap sort is just running very slowly...how do i fix the pop(0)?

Comment: this is the algorithm that i used 
heapsort( list ):
       Create an empty heap.
       While the list is not empty:
               Remove the next value from the list; call it v.
               Add v to the heap.
       While the heap is not empty:
               Remove the next value from the heap; call it w.
               Append w to the list.

Comment: I get the feeling this is a homework assignment written by someone who'd rather be teaching Scheme, and who hasn't bothered to explain the massive differences between Python lists (variable-length arrays, cheap to insert/delete on the right, expensive on the left, and there are better ways to iterate than popping from the right) and Lisp lists (linked lists, cheap to insert/delete on the left, expensive on the right, and repeated cdr'ing is the best way to iterate).

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to write `while alst != []:` and `while heap.size != 0`; just use `while alst:` and `while heap.size:` (or, with a reasonable `heap` class, just `while heap:`). In Python, numeric 0 and empty collections are always falsey, and it is [recommended](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) that you take advantage of that to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `arrayHeap` provides the same guarantees as the stdlib's [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/heapq.html) or any other reasonable heap implementation, then this is a *valid* heap sort, but it's a very silly one.

By copying the original sequence into a list and then popping from the left side, you're doing O(N^2) preparation for your O(N log N) sort.

If you change this to pop from the *right* side, then you're only doing O(N) preparation, so the whole thing takes O(N log N), as a heapsort should.

That being said, I can't understand why you want to pop off the list instead of just iterating over it. Or, for that matter, why you want to copy the original sequence into a list instead of just iterating over it directly. If you do that, it will be faster, and use only half the memory, and be much simpler code. Like this:

```
def heapSort(lst):
    heap = arrayHeap.mkHeap(len(lst), arrayHeap.less)
    for v in lst:
        arrayHeap.add(heap, v)
    alst = []
    while heap.size:
        w = arrayHeap.removeMin(heap)
        alst.append(w)
    return last
```

With a slightly nicer API, like the one in the stdlib's `heapq` module (is there a reason you're not using it, by the way?), you can make this even simpler:

```
def heapSort(lst):
    alst = []
    for v in lst:
        heapq.heappush(alst, v)
    return [heapq.heappop(alst) for i in range(len(alst))]
```

… or, if you're sure `lst` is a list and you don't mind mutating it:

```
def heapSort(lst):
    heapq.heapify(lst)
    return [heapq.heappop(lst) for i in range(len(lst))]
```

… or, of course, you can copy `lst` and then mutate the copy:

```
def heapSort(lst):
    alst = lst[:]
    heapq.heapify(alst)
    return [heapq.heappop(alst) for i in range(len(alst))]
```

You may notice that the first one is the first of the [Basic Examples](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) in the `heapq` docs.

Comment: well i was required to have a copy.

Comment: heapSort.py – where you use the functions in arrayHeap.py to create a heap-sort implementation (Don’t forget that the array returned has to be a copy, and that the original list is unchanged.)

Comment: @user3059815: Iterating the input sequence into the heap _already_ makes a copy. You don't have to make a copy so you can copy it.

Comment: is there anything that i can enhance for the w?

Comment: it is still running very slowly....am i not doing this right?
def heapSort(lst):
    
    alst = []
    for v in lst:
        heappush(alst, v)
    return [heapq.heappop(alst) for i in range(len(alst))]

    while heap.size != 0:
        w = arrayHeap.removeMin(heap)
        alst.append(w)
    return alst

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testSorts.run('heapSort')

Comment: @user3059815: Unfortunately, SO comments throw away all multi-line formatting, which makes it impossible to read any code you put there (especially Python code). If you can't/shouldn't edit it into your question, post it somewhere else, like pastebin.com or gist, and then post a link here.

Comment: @user3059815: But it looks like you're trying to use _both_ `heapq` and `arrayHeap`. I don't know exactly what you're doing, but you could very easily turn all your logic from `O(N log N)` to `O(N**2 log**2N)` or the like by doing that, so… don't. Just use one or the other.